# symfony2 + fos user bundle, register confirmation mail not receiving

Tags: email, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.4

I installed FOS UserBundle for user login/register. The thing is that after registering, it redirects me on the "../register/check-email" page where it has the well-known message that a mail with the activation link has been sent to the user's email, but I don't receive any e-mail.
My config.yml file has this code for the fos_user:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: IngrijireMedicalaAcasa\AppBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: ingrijiremedicalaacasa_appbundle_registration   
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
    service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.default    
    from_email:
        address:        noreply@anytext.com
        sender_name:    any text
```

Do I have to do any other configuration somewhere?

I mention I tried to change the address "noreply@anytext.com" with my own valid mail address.
I changed even the parameters.yml with my mail details but it still doesn't work.
Oh, and I try to send the mail from my localhost.

I hope you guys know what's the solving to my problem. I think it's a small thing that I don't see, I don't know or I forgot to do it.

Answer (score 1):

try this : (works if your email is gmail (mailer_transport)

```
#app/config/config.yml
//
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
   # host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm # other valid values are 'mongodb', 'couchdb' and 'propel'
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: IngrijireMedicalaAcasa\AppBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        confirmation:
            from_email:
                address:        your.email@gmail.com
                sender_name:    Any Text
            enabled: true
    service:
            mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
```

in your config_dev.yml :

```
//
assetic:
    use_controller: true
swiftmailer:
    transport: gmail
    username:  your.email@gmail.com
    password:  your password
```

in app/config/parameter.yml:

```
//
mailer_transport: gmail
//
```

Comment: thanks for support, I tried and it doesn't work. I still got no mail. I'm wondering, shouldn't it work with the smtp configured by fosuserbundle? and should there be a valid email? couldn't it be just a name like noreply@domain.com or something?